# How do I find the first item in the post array?

Tags: query-posts, array

I left ????? where I need the answer.

```
<?php

global $post;

$the_post_ID = $post->ID;

$n = get_posts();
?>


<?php foreach ( $n as $post ) : ?>

<nav id="postNav">

<ul>
    <li<?php if (?????) echo ' class="current"'; ?>>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten`enter code here`' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li></ul>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get first item using this code

```
<?php

global $post;

$the_post_ID = $post->ID;

$n = get_posts();
$i=1;
?>


<?php foreach ( $n as $post ) : ?>

<nav id="postNav">

<ul>
<li<?php if ($i){ echo ' class="current"'; $i=0; }?>>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__(     'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten`enter code here`' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0'         ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
   </li></ul>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `<li<?php if ($n[0]) echo ' class="current"'; ?>>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>` this doesnt work

Comment: Whats is it displaying?

Comment: if i do if ($n[0]) add class; it just adds the class to all posts im just trying to do is add a class to the first post i just dont know what to write in the ???? part of my code I posted. Any help would be greatful

Comment: Use the above updated code.

Comment: It doesn't make total sense to me But it works Perfectly!!! Thanks your a life saver.